# gcfit output in R package Grofit

Tags: r

I'm trying to do some growth curve fitting in the R package *Grofit*.  I successfully managed to do this with a different dataset last year but since then I think *Grofit* has updated.

Using the latest version of the package I can run the command eg `Test<-grofit(time,data,TRUE)` and get growth curves which look sensible.

However, when I go to output the data using `summary(Test,gcfit)` I get a table which does not contain the growth curve data - eg *mu, lamda etc* but looks like this:

```
        Length Class          Mode   
time    55     data.frame     list   
data    58     data.frame     list   
gcFit    7     gcFit          list   
drFit    1     -none-         logical
control 16     grofit.control list
```

I've tried using the random data which *grofit* can generate and get a similar output.  I'm confused as I'm following exactly the same protocol as I used last year and getting a completely different result!

Comment: The package is listed as "ORPHANED" on CRAN. This could result in it's removal.

Comment: Thanks @Roland, but if the package had been removed I wouldn't be able to install it or run it at all. I can run the grofit command, as evidenced by the growth curve graphical output which I see. Surely if it was not able to be used I wouldn't be able to run it at all? Also, orphaned packages are still available as long as they pass R CMD check....

Comment: It's still available, of course. I'm only suggesting that now might be the time to reconsider depending on it for your work. I don't want to install it, but have you tried `summary(Test$gcFit)`?

Comment: Hi Roland, trouble is that I can't seem to find anything as useful. I tried summary(Test$gcfit) first, as this was what I originally used, but it game me no output at all: length 0, Class, 0, Mode, NULL.  Looking back at the grofit paper led me to try summary(Test,gcfit), also dim(TestTable) where TestTable is the summary output is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked a while ago but in case anyone comes across this problem, this works:

```
fit <- gcFit(time, data, ...)
summary.gcFit(fit)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the full grofit output:

```
Test<-grofit(time,data,TRUE)
sink(file = "Test.txt")
Test
sink()
```

Then you can find the file in your working directory.

You can get the values you need without the function `sink()`. For example, if you need mu values (slopes) of your data use:

```
mu <- test1$gcFit$gcTable$mu.spline
```

For lambda:

```
lambda <- test1$gcFit$gcTable$lambda.spline
```